# Let a div background to invade others divs using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to achieve an effect that a splat of paint is being combined with another splat of paint.

I have 4 columns with 1 splat background each, is there a way to make the background of 1 container interferes with the others in order to show a random splat pattern?

This is what I want to get:
[image: This is the effect I want to achieve]

This is what I got:

```css
section#splat {
  background: #010318;
}

.tag-foto {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bevwr.png);
  height: 410px;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
  width: 290px;
}

.tag-foto-2 {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIwOh.png);
  height: 410px;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
  width: 290px;
}

.tag-foto-3 {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ledX.png);
  height: 410px;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
  width: 290px;
}

.tag-foto-4 {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwMFz.png);
  height: 410px;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
  width: 290px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="splat">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      Title
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="tag-foto">

        </div>
        <p class="region-artista text-center">Text</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="tag-foto-2">

        </div>
        <p class="region-artista text-center">text</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="tag-foto-3">

        </div>
        <p class="region-artista text-center">text</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="tag-foto-4">

        </div>
        <p class="region-artista text-center">text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @isherwood, can you explain to me more about source values? Do you mean that the images on the CSS are not showing?

Comment: Oh, sorry you are right, I was about to put them there, but, for the sake of the question I didn't include them, let me remove them, since it can lead to confusion

Answer (score 1):

I have demoed a few of the most relevant values of [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).

an inset box shadow matching the background color can also help to soften the edges of the images.

```css
section#splat {
  background: #010318;
}

.tag-foto {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bevwr.png);
  height: 410px;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
  aspect-ratio: 267 / 304;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px 4px #010318 inset;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.tag-foto-2 {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIwOh.png);
  height: 410px;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
  aspect-ratio: 267 / 304;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px 4px #010318 inset;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.tag-foto-3 {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ledX.png);
  height: 410px;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
  aspect-ratio: 267 / 304;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.tag-foto-4 {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwMFz.png);
  height: 410px;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
  aspect-ratio: 267 / 304;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="splat">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="tag-foto">
          <img src="" alt="" class="sello-foto">
        </div>
        <p class="region-artista text-center">Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="tag-foto-2">
          <img src="" alt="" class="sello-foto">
        </div>
        <p class="region-artista text-center">text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="tag-foto-3">
          <img src="" alt="" class="sello-foto">
        </div>
        <p class="region-artista text-center">text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="tag-foto-4">
          <img src="" alt="" class="sello-foto">
        </div>
        <p class="region-artista text-center">text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Run the code snippet and click full page to see the effect of the overlapping splatters. The fixed image size in the example doesn't make this the best demo but I was trying to stay focused on the question.

Comment: I see it now. The change is subtle, but nice. The small bits of splatter overlap. I guess I didn't get what was being requested by the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is not what I'm looking for, nonetheless if I can't find any other approach, I'll be using your solution.